# How to download Instagram Profile Picture (InstaDP) with high quality?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to know how can someone download an Instagram profile picture in high resolution (like these websites: [InstaDP](http://Instadp.com), [izoomyou](http://izoomyou.app), etc.) without any third-party apps or websites.
These pictures can't be downloaded with the "src" attribute because it gives you a 320x320 low-resolution picture.
I read some of the questions and answers from this site but those methods don't work anymore.
If someone knows how to do this please write it here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide example profile

Answer (score 0):

you can try this web `Fullinstadp.com`
you just insert `username` and then click `view`
and next choose `Download Full Size DP`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).